# questions on javascript - string.replace()

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I was trying to run this line of code and wondering why it is not working. Does anyone has an answer for this?

```
var string = "foo     bar";
string = string.replace(" ", "");
alert(string.length);
```

why issit that the length of the string is not changed to 6 instead?

Answer (score 4):

The function only replaces one instance of the string you search for.

To replace more, you can match with a regular expression:

```
string = string.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

That strips all "whitespace" characters. The "\s" matches whitespace, the "+" means "one or more occurrences" of whitespace characters, and the trailing "g" means "do it to all matching sequences in the string".

Answer (score 2):

Because you have more than one `space` in your string and the `.replace` is replacing one space, the first one encountered.

This works as expected, with only one space

```
var string = "foo bar";
string = string.replace(" ", "");
alert(string.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

replace, when passed a string as the first parameter, only replaces the first occurrence of that string.  To replace everything, you'd need a regular expression:

```
alert("foo     bar".replace(/ /g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because only one space has been replaced. Per JavaScript 1.5 specification, `String.replace()` takes a regular expression as first parameter and the behavior for string parameters is undefined. Browsers later decided to treat strings similarly - but there is no way to specify `g` flag on a string, so only one replacement is done. This will do what you want:

```
string = string.replace(/ /g, '');
```

The version provided by Pointy (`/\s+/g`) might be more efficient however. And it will replace other types of whitespace (tabs, newlines) as well.